# datasets on international cross-border trade by mode of transportation

Tags: transportation, global, trade

I'm looking for datasets on the volume and value of goods transported across international borders by different modes of transportation, such as air, sea, road, and rail. Specifically, I'm interested in the percentage of goods transported by air, and data that shows the growth in the volume of freight transported over time.

I've checked data portals such as IATA, World Bank and UN Comtrade, but haven't been able to find the specific data I'm looking for. I'm wondering if you know of any other sources or datasets that might provide this information, preferably at a global or regional level. Thank you!